# Printing Arrays in D

Tags: arrays, printing, formatting, d

How do I most conveniently print array of numeric values in D? Are there such highlevel overloads or do I have to implement them myself?

In my case I just want to display the contents of `data` to check the result of.

```
  double data[] = [ 11,2,3,4,6,1,34 ];
  std.algorithm.sort(data);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend you go through D language specification which is available on http://dlang.org . You would find many encounters of writeln() there - it prints out almost everything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just import `std.stdio` and use `writeln()` on the array.

```
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    auto a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    writeln(a);
}
```

Comment: I thought I had to use `printf`. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Have you even tried?

```
foreach(a; data) writeln(a);
```